# in reactive form, value is not updating in formConrtoslname while control have value

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, angular-reactive-forms

I create the reactive form using this code.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.create_form();
 }

 create_form() {
   this.form_group = this.form_builder.group({
     apiCommands: this.form_builder.array([this.formField()]),
   })
 }

 formField() {
   return this.form_builder.group({
     action: ['', [Validators.required]],
     ue: [[], [Validators.required]],
     catName: ['All'],
   })
 }

 get formArr() {
   return this.form_group.get('apiCommands') as FormArray;
 }
```

there are some dependencies in **action** section. when someone select some specific value from **action**, some new controls will add on that perticuler index.
**Ex: action = "some value"**
then 2 more controls will add also will show on frontend.

this is the array json

```
[
        {
            "label": "Address Type",
            "name": "addresstype",
            "type": "dropdown",
            "class": "inline-fields",
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "IPv4",
                    "value": "4",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "name": "IPv6",
                    "value": "6",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "name": "IPv4/IPv6",
                    "value": "10",
                    "checked": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Context Id",
            "name": "contextId",
            "type": "number",
            "required": true,
            "class": "inline-fields"
        }
    ],
```

```
     select_Action_Name(action_name, index) {
        this.opArray.splice(index, 1, API_ADDITIONAL_PARAM[action_name]);
        if (this.opArray[index]?.length || this.opArray[index] == !undefined)
          this.opArray[index].forEach((d) => {
            this.form_group.controls['apiCommands']['controls'][index]['controls'
               [d.name] = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
          });
      }
```

after selection, controls is adding, and also frontend bind. but when we select the value which is add controls dynamiclay, value is not updating while controls have value.
**also please check the Attached image of form_group. why value not update, while controls have value**